# Pandas: Replace column values in DataFrame based on the json object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json object called 'countries' like below with all the countries ISO code list:

```
countries = [{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha-2":"AF","country-code":"004"},{"name":"Åland Islands","alpha-2":"AX","country-code":"248"},{"name":"Albania","alpha-2":"AL","country-code":"008"},{"name":"Algeria","alpha-2":"DZ","country-code":"012"}]
```

I have a pandas dataframe with 'Country' column:

```
Country
--------
Albania
Algeria
Algeria
```

I want to replace the Country column 'name' with the 'alpha-2' value from the json object. The result should be like :

```
Country
---------
AL
DZ
DZ
```

I am trying to do something like this which does not give any error nor changes the values.

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace(lambda y: (x['alpha-2'] for x in countries) if y in (x['name'] for x in countries) else y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A row-wise `lambda` is not recommended with Pandas, for the same reason `pd.Series.apply` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/9209546). A much better idea is to construct a single mapping dictionary and then use vectorised [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
# setup dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Albania', 'Algeria', 'Algeria']})

# construct mapping dictionary and apply mapping
mapper = {dct['name']: dct['alpha-2'] for dct in countries}
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(mapper).fillna(df['Country'])

print(df)
#   Country
# 0      AL
# 1      DZ
# 2      DZ
```

Comment: This is good in the sense OP wants convert the json to a single map +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way to make a new `{country:country_code}` dictionary pattern using `country_to_country_code= {v['name']:v['alpha-2'] for v in countries}` and then just `map()` your **Country** column with this `country_to_country_code` dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":["Albania", "Algeria", "Algeria"]})
countries = [{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha-2":"AF","country-code":"004"},{"name":"Åland Islands","alpha-2":"AX","country-code":"248"},{"name":"Albania","alpha-2":"AL","country-code":"008"},{"name":"Algeria","alpha-2":"DZ","country-code":"012"}]

country_to_country_code= {v['name']:v['alpha-2'] for v in countries}
df.loc[:, 'Country'] = df['Country'].map(country_to_country_code)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  Country
0      AL
1      DZ
2      DZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a column `Country` in `df['Country']` so if you have other fields as well like one in question `alpha-2` then why not simply `df['Country']=df['alpha-2']` which will be faster than `lambda` anyways

Answer (score 0):

If You have already converted the Json into pandas dataFrame and you have the DataFrame as you have shown with the column `Country` then you either simply can use `map()` function or use `replace()` method both will work here.

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map({'Albania': 'AL', 'Algeria': 'DZ'})
```

OR:

```
>>> df.Country.replace(to_replace=dict(Albania='AL', Algeria='DZ'))
0    AL
1    DZ
2    DZ
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

OR  alternatively you can create a dictionary to make multiple replacements at a time as follows.

```
new_vals = {
  'Albania': 'AL',
  'Algeria': 'DZ',
  }


df['Country'].replace(new_vals)
# df['Country'].replace(new_vals, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think the problem is OP is starting with the json object, so they are looking for a way to convert the json to a single map (if using `pd.Series.map`).

Comment: @jpp, that's may be true :-)  , otherwise `map()`  would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to a Pandas DataFrame (e.g. df2) and then do a replace.

```
import pandas as pd

countries = [{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha-2":"AF","country-code":"004"},{"name":"Åland Islands","alpha-2":"AX","country-code":"248"},{"name":"Albania","alpha-2":"AL","country-code":"008"},{"name":"Algeria","alpha-2":"DZ","country-code":"012"}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(countries)

co = [('Country', ['Afghanistan', 'Algeria', 'Albania'])]  # your original dataframe with country
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(co)



df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].replace(df2.set_index('name')['alpha-2'])

df1 should look like:
[enter image description here][1]
```